# Return data from method in object

Tags: javascript-objects

I have been trying to figure this one out and I'm not getting how to return the data to another method and call it so that I don't have to statically add the data into my request. I keep getting undefined data on my B2C method when I run it for the data returned from this.O_Auth. Any clues?

```
let obj = {
    O_Auth(key, secret) {
        const key = Key;
        const secret = Secret;
        const auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(key + ":" + secret).toString("base64");

        request(
            {
                uri: "https://randomurl",
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": auth
                }
            },
            (err, res, body) => {
                if (err) {
                    return err;
                } else {
                    // console.log(body);

                    let response = JSON.parse(body);
                    let res = JSON.stringify(response.access_token)
                    return res;

                }
            }
        );
    },
    B2C(params) {
        console.log("Random " + this.O_Auth('first', 'second'));
        let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://randomurl',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.O_Auth('first', 'second'),
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: {
                //values
            },
            json: true
        };

        rp(options)
            .then(function (body) {
                console.log(body);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out the asynchronous nature of JavaScript meant I was requesting data that was being evaluated later so I used a promise to get the data and output it first before using it in a subsequent promise that outputs the body. Changed the first request to request promise (rp) that returns the options that will be needed for that promise in the second method.

```
    let obj = {
    O_Auth(Key, Secret) {
        const key = Key;
        const secret = Secret;
        const auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(key + ":" + secret).toString("base64");

     let options = {
                uri: "https://randomurl",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": auth
                },
                json: true
            };

        return rp(options)   
    },
    B2C(param1, param2, param3...) {
        this.O_Auth('first', 'second'))then(response =>{
        let token = response.access_token;
        let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://randomurl',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: {
                //values
            },
            json: true
        };

        rp(options)
            .then(function (body) {
                console.log(body);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```